# Как себя ведут свойства длины и ширины у flex-контейнера?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Чего я никак не могу понять при работе с flexbox, так это особенности поведения длины и ширины контейнера. Достаточно много информации о том, как себя ведут размеры элементов внутри контейнера, но мало - о том, как ведёт себя длина и ширина контейнера.

Из того, что я обнаружил экспериментальным путём:

- flex-контейнер не растягивается на `100%` ширины родителя, как блочные элементы
- На `min-height` реакции нет.

Конкретезирую вопрос: что применительно к flex-контенеру значат следующие css-свойства?

- `width`
- `min-width`
- `max-width`
- `height`
- `min-height`
- `max-width`

Comment: К сожалению ответить не могу, ибо там очень сложно, но дам вам ссылку на очень хорошую статью. [11 вещей которые я узнал, читая спецификацию flexbox](https://habrahabr.ru/post/329820/)

Comment: @Виталик Черный, не так всё просто вo `flexbox`, как это преподностися новичками ^ ^ "Флексбок очень прост в обращении и легко осваивается" и т. д.

Comment: то есть вы хотите сказать, что хорошо понимаете как работают алгоритм вычисления ширины у флекс элементов, а если быть точнее свойства: `flex: none | [ <'flex-grow'> <'flex-shrink'>? || <'flex-basis'> ]`. Вы слишком высокомерен по моему личному мнению.

Comment: @Виталик Черный ни в коем разе. Прошу прощения, что непонятно выразился. Я констатировал факт, что оказывается с флексбоксом не всё так просто, как я об этом ранее читал в уроках. А потом я привёл примерную фразу, которая обычно заявляется в уроках (например [http://html5.by/blog/flexbox/](здесь)).